# Why does all() return True for an empty iterable?

Tags: python, iterable

My understanding of `all()` is that it returns `True` if every value if an iterable is `True` when evaluated as a boolean.

`bool([]) == False`, so why does `all([])` return `True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). Since there's nothing in the list, there's no false elements in the list, and `all` only returns False if at least one of its inputs is False. Since all zero elements in the list are true, `all` returns True.